# I am trying to run migrations but when i run migrate.py I get a type error?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I GET A BIG ERROR BUT THE MAIN THING I GET IS :

> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, app, auth,
>   contenttypes, sessions, subscribe Running migrations:   Applying
>   app.0019_auto_20190224_0449...Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Ubaid
>   Parveez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py",
>   line 106, in parse_datetime
>       match = datetime_re.match(value) `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Here's the `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from tinymce import HTMLField



class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = HTMLField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog',kwargs = {
            'pk':self.pk
            })

    @property
    def get_comments(self):
        return self.comments.all()




class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name = "comments")
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name



class Upload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images')
    content = models.FileField(upload_to = 'images/%Y/%M/%d')
```

Comment: What was your output after doing `./manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: It was normal .No errors at that time

Comment: Can you try adding a default value for the datetime field in `published_date` as `default=datetime.now()`?

Comment: Please show the migration `0019_auto_20190224_0449` which is failing

Comment: @Sanip I still get that error after adding you,r datetime.now()

Comment: Can you show the migration file 0019_auto_20190224_0449.py as requested by @Alasdair?

Comment: where is that file located?

Comment: It’s in your app’s `migrations` folder.